# Launching application when receiving on DATA_SMS_RECEIVED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I have declared a broadcast receiver in manifest for receiving `DATA_SMS_RECEIVED`, the broadcast receiver triggered when the application is running, but when the application is closed nothing happens and no broadcasts are received.

```
<receiver android:name="edu.sharif.iis.khasis.SmsReceiver"  android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        <data android:scheme="sms" android:host="*" android:port="8901" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I have tested this scheme with `BOOT_COMPLETED` and it works well, but doesn't works with `DATA_SMS_RECEIVED`. could someone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Add this

```
<action android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

It is OS generated action.

Comment: sorry try again I have udated my answer.

Comment: No. That's a permission